# Upgrading from Bootstrap 4.0 to 4.5

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am trying to upgrade from Bootstrap 4.0.0 to 4.5.0 on my WordPress. From reading another thread, I believe I simply need to find certain files and replace the 4.0.0 versions with 4.5.0 versions., specifically CSS and JS folders.

I downloaded the 4.5.0 source files from Bootstrap's website. In the WordPress site theme I have active, I see inside /node_modules/bootstrap/ a collection of folders that match folders inside the Bootstrap 4.5.0 source files I downloaded. Specifically (all at the same level):

- A folder titled "dist" with subfolders "css" and "js"; the contents
  appear very similar between the source files and what I already have
- A folder titled "js" with subfolders "dist" and "src"; the contents
  appear very similar between the source files and what I already have,
  but the source files folder also has a folder "tests" that is not on
  my existing site
- A folder titled "scss" with subfolders "mixins" and "utilities" as
  well as a number of .scss files; the contents appear very similar
  between the source files and what I already have

There are also some stray files in the /node_modules/bootstrap/ folder (LICENSE, package.json and README.md) that are also in the 4.5.0 source files.

All of this makes me feel that this is the place I need to replace the 4.0.0 files with the 4.5.0 files. However there are several files in the 4.5.0 source files not present in /node_modules/bootstrap/:

- _config.yml
- a folder "build" with various .js files
- CNAME
- CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
- composer.json
- Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock
- package-lock.json
- package.js
- SECURITY.md

From my limited understanding, I think the 4.5.0 source files have more than any given person may need, and that makes me think these files may not be essential for my purposes, if they are not already in the /node_modules/bootstrap/ folder on my existing site. I'm also in a dev environment, so I could just give it a go and see what happens.

My other concern is, I see in /dist/styles/main.css there is what appears to be all the 4.0.0 css, as well as additional css for plugins. Do I need to manually update the portion of this css file with the 4.5.0 css?

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid updating node_modules manually as the packages listed there were created by a package manager (more than likely, npm) and as such specific versions were installed with dependencies. Editing files in there can break your app!

If you can, look for a package.json file in the parent folder of node_modules and update the version of bootstrap in there, then run `npm install` in the terminal.

Comment: OK, thank you! I did locate the package.json file in the parent of node_modules. I see toward the end of the file's contents, in "dependencies", an entry of:

"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta"

So I can literally change the first zero to a five, and then run npm install without pointing to a folder? I guess I assumed I needed to specify Bootstrap 4.5.0 at that point.

Comment: I reckon you'll already be sorted with this, @partydarb, but yes: updating the version number then running the install should update the version without any more input.